# Using GitHub actions, how can I pass the Python files from PR to pytest?

Tags: python, pytest, github-actions, cicd

In my GH Action, I am getting all the changed files in the PR. How do I pass each Python file to pytest? (I don't want to run pytest on the whole directory just the changed files.) This is the `jobs` section my current code:

```
jobs:
  build:
    name: Testing Python Files
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    # Required permissions to run the action
    permissions:
      contents: read
      pull-requests: read
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Get all the changed files
        id: changed-files
        uses: tj-actions/changed-files@v42
        # To compare changes between the current commit and the last pushed remote commit set `since_last_remote_commit: true`. e.g
        with:
          since_last_remote_commit: true

      - name: Set up Python 3.10
        uses: actions/setup-python@v5
        with:
          python-version: "3.10"

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install pytest

      - name: Testing Python files
        run: |
          for file in ${{ steps.changed-files.outputs.all_changed_files }}; do
            # Check for Python solution files
            if [[ $file == *.py ]]; then
                echo "Testing $file"
                pytest $file
            fi
         done
```

The output I get is:

```
Testing Lessons/Intro-to-Python/1/Activities/01-Ins_Python_Intro/Solved/variables_solution.py
======================== test session starts =========================
platform linux -- Python 3.10.13, pytest-8.0.1, pluggy-1.4.0
rootdir: /home/runner/work/GitHub-Actions-Playground/GitHub-Actions-Playground
collected 0 items
===================== no tests ran in 0.01s =======================
Error: Process completed with exit code 5.
```

Comment: This seems to be missing a few lines at the end (with `fi` and `done`), so it's hard to tell what's going on. How is it not working for you, currently?

Comment: @BenjaminW. I forgot to add `fi` and `done`. I added the error above.

Answer (score 0):

## Why doesn't it work?

Firstly, let's check what does exit code 5 mean [HERE](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference/exit-codes.html)

```
Exit code 5: No tests were collected
```

Then the answer is simple, `Testing Lessons/Intro-to-Python/1/Activities/01-Ins_Python_Intro/Solved/variables_solution.py` has no tests.

And as this fails on first file it doesn't even check next.

## Solutions

1. Filter out files without tests or run only those having tests.
2. Ignore errors. In bash this is done with `set -e` (but please, don't do it)
3. You can also do tricky one (below)

#### Tricky one

1. Create simple `always_runned_test.py` file. This will always be executed (to be sure that there is at least one test to be run - preventing exit code 5)
2. Execute `pytest ${{ steps.changed-files.outputs.all_changed_files }} always_runned_test.py` in your pipeline - all files and at least one test.

Comment: Thanks @ravenwing. I decided not to add a test file since I have so many different Python files. Instead, I just want to use Python to run each changed Python file in the PR. How do I pass the `$file` to  `python ../scripts/python_test.py`? Currently, I am getting the following error:

`python: can't open file '/home/runner/work/GitHub-Actions-Playground/GitHub-Actions-Playground/../scripts/python_testing.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.`

Comment: Well... please create new question for that including your directory structure and pipeline code. Paste link to that and I'll have a look :)

Comment: I decided that the easier option at the moment was to just execute the file using Python, `python $file`.